# Speeding up <canvas> pixel-reads

Tags: canvas, optimization

I'm practicing with a little single-page-application which uses web-workers to parallel process some pixel calculations which involve extensive looping,  hence delegating them to the web-workers.

However, in order to do this I'm having to first turn the pixels into data for the web-worker to use, and this means going through all of the pixels in the canvas tag to log each pixel data into an array.

```
    const jImgNode = $(imgNode);
    const allPointsArray = [];
    const cvs = $("#temp-canvas")[0];
    const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgNode, 0, 0);
    const thisWidth = jImgNode.attr("data-width") * 1;
    const thisHeight = jImgNode.attr("data-height") * 1;
    for (let x = 0; x < thisWidth; x++) {
        allPointsArray.push([]);
        let col = allPointsArray[allPointsArray.length - 1];
        for (let y = 0; y < thisHeight; y++) {
            let currentPixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
            // capture the color array of all the pixels: [r, g, b, a]
            col.push(currentPixel);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that there's a series of images to read this way, and I'm first doing a main-thread loop of all these images to perform the above code and then send a Promise over to a web-worker with the data.

While doing one or two of such pixel-reads is no problem, it is clearly blocking and conspicuously renders the browser unresponsive as it goes through this first loop creating temporary divs and canvas tags for every image item so that it can then be read via the snippet above. Although it takes only about 1s to process the pixel array, these processes have to all run from start to end before the first web-worker promise can go out.

Perhaps it could be a problem with my promises and maybe there's some way to change them such that they do trigger after each pixel-map read instead of after the last pixel-map read - but for now I'd like to ask if there's a function or technique which would allow much faster pixel-reading from a canvas tag.

I am considering doing things like exploring re-use of one temporary element and one temporary canvas tag, or even using a humongous 'sprite' canvas which is very tall and contains all of the images I'd like to process as a grid so that a pixel-reading function could run through it one time and push out the various individual-grid-cell arrays representing each separate image. However I'm quite weary to do a bunch of work changing the code to try this and get a similar or worse result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ctx.getImageData(x, y, width, height)*'s *width* and *height* arguments can be set to higher values than `1`, so you can grab the pixel data of more than a single pixel.

If you want to send the whole context's pixel data, then

```
img = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
```

will give it to you.

Now `img.data` will be a flat Uint8ClampedArray containing all the r,g,b and a channel values of all your pixels. You'll then have to loop by four in order to get each pixel values:

```
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
  let r = data[i];
  let g = data[i + 1];
  let b = data[i + 2];
  let a = data[i + 3];
  ....
```

Then since you are using web workers, you might also be interested in the fact that you can transfer the buffer to your worker context instead of copying it (less memory usage => less GC => better perfs).
To do so, pass the ImageData's TypedArray's buffer in an Array as the second argument of Worker.postMessage:

```
worker.postMessage(img, [img.data.buffer]);
```

Comment: This looks to be like the answer, but as for the bonus part of it, I am getting this following error: `Exception: TypeError: Method get %TypedArray%.prototype.buffer called on incompatible receiver [object Object]`
Wonder why that is happening.
[Nevermind] - It was I didn't have the .data as the place where I was looking for the .buffer properly.

Comment: @VasilyHall, uh? That's a weird error message. Could you set up a fiddle so that I can see how you got there? Here is one with the full minimal code: https://jsfiddle.net/p30orctv/ Ps: I might not answer back before a few hours though.

Comment: Well it was a typo on my part, I'm very close to seeing how it works- just need to convert the new array buffer into an array and then into my column/row array inside that web-worker.

Comment: OH. MY. GOD.
I am speechless.
Oh my God.
We went from 1m to 10s. This is certainly the most exciting thing that could have happened, I'm grateful to say the least, for your advice!